# Call/Reuse AccountController Logoff internally in server

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an AccountController action as follows which works fine from a browser:

```
       [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff(string returnUrl)
```

I have situations where the user claims are "stale" and I must force a logout server-side. The quick-fix for this is to create an internal function with the content of the function above. However, I was wondering if there is a way to (easily) reuse this interface from my (non-controller) server code. I could abuse? the HttpClient to do this but I suspect there is a simpler way to reuse internally?

Comment: One suggestion could be that, you can define the `LogOff` functionality in `WebApi`, now you can call this method from your MVC project and also internally

Comment: What situation do your claims become stale? Can you not just refresh them? I use Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions's OnValidateIdentity identity which allows you to force a refresh after a specified time.

Comment: thx. I'll take a look. I'm using owin but already have a working logoff/login that I thought to reuse...

Answer (score 1):

In your `AccountController` create a method that will encapsulate all the logic of invalidating identity of current user:

```
    [NonAction]
    public async Task InvalidateUser()
    {
        // CreateIdentityForCurrentUser is your function 
        // that create fresh claims identity for the current user
        ClaimsIdentity identity = CreateIdentityForCurrentUser(); 

        var ctx = this.Request.GetOwinContext();
        var authManager = ctx.Authentication;

        authManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant = new AuthenticationResponseGrant(
            new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), 
            new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false });
    }
```

With this method you won't have logoff/login the user in order to refresh it's claims.

You can call from any other method in your server

Comment: Looks good, but my current CreateIdentity is based on an external callback from Auth0: static ClaimsIdentity CreateIdentity(ClaimsIdentity externalIdentity) so I'm asking there how to proceed in this case.